# Google maps JavaScript API doesn't use latest imagery

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The current version of the Google maps JS API uses different satellite imagery than google maps itself. I couldn't find any documentation related to this discrepancy and would love to know if there is a way to force the API to use the *actual* most up to date imagery (which it claims to do by default).

```
// Example:
```

Here's an example of the [JS API](https://codepen.io/jpschroeder/pen/ENoWbv) not matching up with [Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@38.0359944,-78.5032185,175m/data=!3m1!1e3)

**Conclusion:**
The Google Earth and Google Maps "satellite" imagery are different. Google Earth data has a mix of older and newer imagery. Many browsers show the Google Earth imagery on the https://maps.google.com which is why there is often a notable discrepancy between that imagery and what you see in the API (which exclusively uses the "satellite" imagery).

Comment: What makes you think that the API isn't using the most up to date imagery?

Comment: @JarodMoser because https://maps.google.com has newer imagery.

Comment: Google Earth is not newer... Just different. Here is a comparison showing a location with [maps api](https://codepen.io/jpschroeder/pen/jVYLeq) vs [google earth](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.436337,-111.8693552,1530m/data=!3m1!1e3) where the api has newer data. Notice that the "Ancestry" building is missing in the google earth image

Comment: Right you are sir. Thanks for the correction, I've updated my conclusion.

Comment: I'm living same issue , is there a way to make it up to date view for satellite view when using google map api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you have access to the same tiles. Technically, they could censor your tiles or perform transformations. But I'm not sure I have ever encountered those discrepancies you are mentioning.

Both your links show the exact same satellite view (HYBRID or SATELLITE).

On a side not, Google Earth uses different tiles and projections.

Comment: You're correct, the google earth imagery is different (and newer) than the "satellite" imagery. I didn't know that. Interestingly google maps displays the earth imagery in most browsers (for some reason it still shows the "satellite" view in safari for me). I didn't realize they were different data sets.